# How to transfer data into a datagrid?

Tags: c#, sql, datagridview, file-transfer

I defined a column in a database as `yyyy/mm/dd hh:hh:hh`. Now , I want to transfer the data that I get from Visual Studio by between `datetimepicker1` and `datetimepicker2` to a `datagridview`. Is there any way to do that?

This is the code that I wrote but I get an error from this line:

```
adp = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from tablo where tablo.tarih >= 
      @StartDateTime AND tablo.tarih <= @EndDateTime", baglanti);

adp.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StartDateTime", 
      Convert.ToDateTime(dtpBaslangic.Value));
adp.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EndDateTime", 
      Convert.ToDateTime(dtpBitis.Value));
```

Comment: Can you provide error text?

Comment: I doubt this make sense: `yyyy/mm/dd hh:hh:hh`. And why isn't your code aligned?

Answer (score 1):

DataSet ds = new DataSet();

adp.Fill(ds);

dataGridView.DataSource = ds.Tables[0]